# Difficulty with manual creation of a Stack using a For Loop

Tags: java, stack, computer-science

The psuedo-code our professor provided is as follows:

```
Node Head; 
int N; //(# of nodes in the stack)
if (N > 0) { 
  Head = CurrentNode //She never creates a current node? 
  for (int x = 0; x < (n-1); x++) { //I don't understand the n-1.

       CurrentNode.setLink(Head); 
       Head = CurrentNode; 

  } else { 

     System.out.println("No Stack Possible"); 

   } if (N == 0) { 
     Head = Null; 
   }
}
```

When the professor wrote this psuedo-code (as a sketch), she either didn't explain it well or I just could not understand it (this is all she gave us for Stacks). For this reason, I am having trouble re-creating the code. I can make a Stack Data Structure using the push method due to looking it up on the internet, but the final is fill in the blank, so I'd like to make sure I understand how to do it her way. The following is my attempt:

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
import java.util.Random; 
public class Stack
{
public static void main(String[] args) { 
    Node head= null;
    head = generateStack(); 
    Print(head); 

} 
public static Node generateStack() { 

    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    Node head = new Node (randomGenerator.nextInt(100),null);
    Node currentNode = head; 
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
    System.out.println("Please enter the amount of Nodes you would 
    like to enter."); 
    int N = input.nextInt(); 
    Node newNode = null; 
    if (N > 0) { 

        for (int i = 0; i < (N-1); i++) { 

            newNode = new Node (randomGenerator.nextInt(100),null)
            currentNode.setLink(newNode); //push
            head = currentNode; 

        } 

    } else {  

        System.out.println("No Stack Possible!"); 

    }
    if (N==0) { 

        head = null; 

    } return head; 

}
 public static void Print(Node entry)
{   
    Node Current = entry; 
    while (Current != null){ 
        System.out.print(Current.getData() + " -> ");
        Current = Current.getLink(); 
    }
}
}
```

The Node Class:

```
public class Node
{
private int data;
private Node link

public Node(int ndata, Node nlink)
{
    data = ndata; 
    link = nlink; 

}

public int getData(){
    return data; 
}

public Node getLink(){
    return link;
}

public void setData(int mydata){
    data = mydata; 
}

public void setLink(Node mylink){
    link = mylink; 
}
}
```

Unfortunately, the code only creates 2 Nodes when I put 3 as my user-input. I tried it by making the for loop just go to N, however, it didn't make a difference. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: @GBlodgett I believe that as well, I just don't understand the pseudocode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I understand what your professor wants. You're code is almost correct. The only thing you did wrong is the content of the for loop. According to your professor it should be:

```
CurrentNode.setLink(Head); 
Head = CurrentNode;
```

The only thing your professor didn't do in there is to create a new CurrentNode. So that code will translate as something like this using what you've done so far:

```
currentNode = new Node (randomGenerator.nextInt(100),null);
currentNode.setLink(head); //push
head = currentNode;
```

Other than that your code look fine.

Comment: Thank you! It worked. Do you also understand why the code inside of the for loop is N-1?

Comment: Yes, it's N-1 because you've created the first element with this line `Node head = new Node (randomGenerator.nextInt(100),null);` so there are only N-1 elements left to be created inside the for loop.